# DNA and Genes, which consists of which? It seems that the hot answer on quora is different to the nih post

Tags: genetics, dna

This quora's [answer](https://qr.ae/TWvAQZ) has got 8.3k views and 20 Upvoters.

"Genes are a part of the DNA."

per [nih](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/basics/gene), "Genes are made up of DNA, which is telling the truth."

in my understanding, the quora version indicate that

> DNA consists of Genes, and DNA is bigger than a gene, in the context of same living thing, such as a specific escherichia coli.

while the nih version indicate that

> Genes consists of DNA, and a gene is bigger than DNA, in the context of same living thing, such as a specific escherichia coli.

did I misunderstand somewhere?

Comment: What difference does "part of" and "made of" makes in your mind? How does it change your conception of what DNA and genes are and aren't?

Comment: @Remi.b Which one is bigger in your mind, in the context of same species, such as escherichia coli?

Comment: Bigger between what and what? The expression "made of" cannot be said to be bigger/smaller than the expression "part of". I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Oh did you mean "is DNA bigger than a gene?". The question has bad semantic but anyway... yes DNA is bigger than a gene. DNA is a massive molecule. Specific locations on this molecule cde for proteins. These sequences are called genes.

Comment: @Remi.b thanks for your reminder, I've updated the post.

Comment: I don't find the text you quote on the linked page. Also, can you add a more informative title for your question?

Comment: As @kmm points out,  the quote you include doesn't actually appear in the NIH article you link to. You may want to go back to that article and re-read it. Were you reading a Google Translate version of it by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

DNA is a large molecule which is particular interest relies in the succession of nucleotide that composes it. The genetic information is contained in the succession of nucleotides (I will ignore epigenetics here for simplicity). A given position of any length on the DNA molecule is called a locus.

A gene is typically defined as a protein coding sequence. In other words, a gene is a locus. A gene is not so much a structural element that makes the DNA, it is rather a functional element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Take this example, AADACL3 on chromosome 1, thanks again for that question, is a gene. in the meanwhile, is it also a DNA? it seem to be not, "DNA basically contains two copies of 23 chromosomes each" from that quora post.